# What are limitations and specifications for numeric data in Excel XML format?

Tags: xml, excel, spreadsheet

I need to deal with Excel XML format (also called XML Spreadsheet 2003 format). *That is not XSLX aka OpenXML format, but the prior XML format.*

When i create a numerc field i cannot see what limitations and specifications take place. For example Excel 2010 fails with `<ss:Data ss:Type="Number"> 8.90000000000000E+0001</ss:Data>` and works like a charm with `<ss:Data ss:Type="Number"> 8E+1</ss:Data>`

There should be some specifications how long the number can be and which symbols are used in its representation (decimal separator are always dots or not? for example)

[Microsoft docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140066.aspx#odc_xmlss_ss%3adata) are scarce as ever and do not explain the data format. Nor does [XML standard](http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_float.html), dunno if it applies to Excel XML or not.

Comment: Dear moderators. I stressed - that is NOT ABOUT XLSX, OpenXML or ECMA

Comment: This particular issue would caused by space in front of the number. Excel only allowed spaces after the number in XMLSS format. Also OpenXML imposed restriction for the exponent always be capital "E", not small "e". Still i'd liek to see formal specification if it exists.

Comment: I did a cursory search and got this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=101 Didn't find anything specific but maybe you can (if you trawl through...). But to the question at hand. My experience with Excel suggests that Excel stores plain numbers up to 17 significant figures. For example, 6876.2857298750996 or 72.629836732699999. Don't use the scientific notation. Instead, use style formatting to set the display format. And if I'm not wrong, use the decimal point when storing. The relevant thousand separator and decimal character is determined by the display format.

Comment: > The relevant thousand separator and decimal character is determined by the display format.
No, definitely. In Soviet tradition TS was dot and DS was comma. In modern Russian use TS is space and DS is comma. But in the XML file there should be not TS and dot as DS. Thanks for the link

Comment: @Vincent well, that SDK stil does not specify ss:Data internals :-( perhaps there is nothign but trial and error...

Comment: I suspect the numeric data is invariant culture. So there's no TS, and the DS is always(?) a period. This means the data can be ported around different cultures and the data still means the same thing. Only the display format changes how that data is shown to the user. I'd say any "normal" floating point value that can be assigned to a double variable type (say in C, C#, Java) is probably ok.

Comment: well, well, th fact is that Excel complains onto something, asks to "Recover the workbook" and then loads. OOo loads without problems. XML-SS formats opens in Excel without problems too.

Comment: @VincentTan - terrific! Excel chokes on zero in exponential form! it can take any number - but zero. It only can take zero as integer!!!

Of course SDK Validator had nothing against zero, dunno how Excel managed to parse XLSX floats and why it does not fail at the same exponential form in XML-SS  http://rghost.ru/43302464

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/oxmlsdk/thread/0f8a47df-a8e2-4519-a63d-b15c9725931e